# Sometimes Product not showing on category pages magento 2.1

Tags: php, magento2.1

I have store on magento 2.1. I have added some products to category but after reindexing, flushing cache, deploy. I have checked and done everything which needs to be done after product assignment to categories.

But still on frontend, sometime products are visible and sometime not.

Please help to resolve this issue.